# Ruby : How to convert bytes array to image file (.jpg, .png ...)

Tags: ruby, image, arrays, converters

I received **string representating a bytes array** to a web service :

> "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL
>   ... "

I want to know how to convert the bytes array to image bin file. Are there any gems to do that or do i need to manipulate it with File library.

I read some examples but not great solutions in Ruby.

Do i need first to convert string into bytes array and after file ? And what is the **extention** that i have to use ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That looks base64 encoded

Comment: First question is how do you get that data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to the 1st part of your question
Your input looks like base64. so I'll assume you need to first decode from base64:

```
binary_data = Base64.decode64(data_from_web_service)
File.open('file_name', 'wb') {|f| f.write(binary_data)}
```

The answer to your 2nd part (how to detect the file extension) is the trickier part. Doesn't the web service return any information about this? If not, you may be successfull by analysing the magic number of the data.

Comment: Thanks you a lot @koffeinfrei ! That is work for me ! And the extension was .jpg !

Answer (score -1):

Can you not just write the string to a file:

```
File.open('picture.jpg', 'w') { |file| file.puts(string) }
```